# CSS only dropdown menu that can overlap its own class

Tags: html, css

OK not sure I gave this a good title.
In essence I'm trying to do a css only drop menu in a table. This seem to work fine for me except where the following row also has a menu in it. then the top menu when it lists out its menu items slides underneath the next rows menu.

Since both menus (UL) share the same class they get the same z-index. the LI items inside do not seem to inherit/ increase z-index from the parent UL, even if I set them to a higher z-index they still slip underneath.

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9B6Gk/2/

Sorry if the code isn't minimal enough I took out a lot but it still looks messy

HTML

```
<table width="100%" style="font-size:10px">
   <tr class="onhold-row details ">
      <td style="text-align:center;">Mon Jul 22 2012</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Craig</td>
      <td style="padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;">Helpdesk</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Car</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;width:20%">
         <ul class="actions">
            <li><a class="unbillable button" style="cursor:pointer;">Discard</a></li>
            <li class="onhold button active">On Hold</li>
            <li><a class="billable button" style="cursor:pointer;" >Chargable</a></li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </tr>
    <tr><td>Example of a spacing row<br/>Example of a spacing row<br/>Example of a spacing row<br/>Example of a spacing row<br/>Example of a spacing row<br/>Example of a spacing row<br/><td></tr>
   <tr class="onhold-row details ">
      <td style="text-align:center;">Sat Jul 24 2012</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">John</td>
      <td style="padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;">Helpdesk</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Bus</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
         <ul class="actions">
            <li><a class="unbillable button" style="cursor:pointer;" >Discard</a></li>
            <li class="onhold button active">On Hold</li>
            <li><a class="billable button" style="cursor:pointer;"  >Chargable</a></li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="onhold-row details ">
      <td style="text-align:center;">Sun Jul 28 2012</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Paul</td>
      <td style="padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;">Helpdesk</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">Taxi</td>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
         <ul class="actions">
            <li><a class="unbillable button" style="cursor:pointer;" >Discard</a></li>
            <li class="onhold button active">On Hold</li>
            <li><a class="billable button" style="cursor:pointer;"  >Chargable</a></li>
         </ul>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td.ticket,
tr.inv-row td,
tr.col-row td,
tr.bill-row td,
tr.unbill-row td,
tr.open-row td,
tr.onhold-row td {  position:relative; }
.actions {padding:2.5em 0 0 0;height:0;overflow:visible;position:relative;z-index:1000;margin:0;}
.actions li{display:none;padding: 1em;background-color:#FFF;box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);position:relative;z-index:1001;}
.actions:hover li{display:block;}
.actions a.button {display:block;margin:0 0.5em;}
.actions .button.active {color:#FFF;border-radius:20px;padding: 0.5em 1.75em;display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0}
.actions .button.active::after{width: 0; height: 0; content:".";font-size:1em;overflow:hidden;border-left: 6px solid transparent; border-right: 6px solid transparent; border-top: 6px solid #FFF;position: absolute;right: 1.25em;top: 0.8em;}    
td.ticket {padding:5px 0px 8px 10px;font-size:1.2em;}    
tr.inv-row td:first-child:before   {  background-color:green;width: 7px;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; top:-1px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.inv-row.details td{background-color:#e8ffe8}    
tr.col-row td:first-child:before   {  background-color:orange;width: 7px;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; top:-1px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.col-row.details td{background-color:#ffb97e}  
.tix-on-bill.ticket, .tix-on-bill.ticket a {color:#006392 !important;background-color:#D0F0FF;}
.tix-on-bill.ticket:before {  background-color:#50C3FF;width: 100%;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; height:4px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.bill-row .comment {}
.bill-row.details td{background-color:#F0F9FD}
tr.bill-row td:first-child:before   {  background-color:#50c3ff;width: 7px;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; top:-1px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.billable.active {background-color:#50c3ff;}    
.unbill-row.details td{background-color:#F8F7F7; color: #bbb;}
.unbill-row .comment{ color: #bbb;}
tr.unbill-row td:first-child:before {  background-color:#ccc;width: 7px;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; top:-1px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.unbillable.active {background-color:#999;}    
.tix-opened.ticket, .tix-opened.ticket a {color:#4500AD !important;background-color:#e7d0ff;}
.tix-opened.ticket:before {  background-color:#9933ff;width: 100%;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; height:4px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.open-row.details td{background-color:#fef2ff;}
tr.open-row td:first-child:before {  background-color:#9933ff;width: 7px;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; top:-1px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}    
.onhold-row.details td{background-color:#fef2ff;}
tr.onhold-row td:first-child:before {  background-color:#9933ff;width: 7px;  content: ".";font-size:0; position:absolute; top:-1px;left:-1px;bottom:-1px;}
.onhold.active {background-color:#9933ff;}    
.inv-row .comment, .col-row .comment {}
.open-row .comment, .onhold-row .comment{}
```

Comment: Indent and format your CSS. A). No one wants to try and clean up that mess before I even start looking at your problem and B). it obfuscates the problem even from yourself.

Comment: While I get your point, in a syntax highlited editor on a wide screen I prefer single line css. I have used an online css formater and update this version for others who like to read spaced out. http://jsfiddle.net/9B6Gk/8/

Comment: When you're posting on Stackoverflow, your post need to be as clear and concise as possible, not formatted how you look at it in your development environment

Comment: Well, you are in the absolute minority.

Comment: All the inline styles don't help readability/problem solving either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your CSS like below. I have remvoed `z-index` for `main ul` and add less `z-index` for the `button li`.

```
 .actions {
   padding:2.5em 0 0 0;
   height:0;
   overflow:visible;
   position:relative;
   /*z-index:1000;*/
   margin:0;}

  .actions li{
   display:none;
   padding: 1em;
   background-color:#FFF;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
   position:relative;
   z-index:2;}

   .actions .button.active {
    color:#FFF;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding: 0.5em 1.75em;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;
    z-index:1;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9B6Gk/9/)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I see now how I went wrong trying to elevate the main UL rather then the LI that were stacking coming out of it.

Answer (score 0):

remove one css rule

```
.actions {
padding: 2.5em 0 0 0;
height: 0;
overflow: visible;
position: relative;
/* z-index: 99999999999999999; */
margin: 0;
}
```